# NULL value when update data

Tags: asp.net

I had grid view which retrieved data from database and mad update for specific columns but when I did update on columns it give other columns null value what can I do?

note :the columns which had null value I made them readonly because user hadnot permission to edit them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have place the read only you get the null - and its normal, but you need to remove the sql reference for this value

Go to your SqlDataSource on the update command (or other) and remove the read only value that you have place from the update query.

Comment: that I made 
((BoundField)GridView1.Columns[2]).ReadOnly = true;
                    ((BoundField)GridView1.Columns[2]).InsertVisible = false;

Comment: @KarremSaad There is an update command !, there you need to remove/fix the sql query, find it on aspx page (not on code behind)

Comment: this query 

ALTER Proc [dbo].[UpdateTranslation]
(
@Id INT
,@Word NVARCHAR(MAX)
,@Trans_AR NVARCHAR(MAX)
,@Trans_EN NVARCHAR(MAX)


)
AS
BEGIN 
UPDATE  Translation SET

Word =@Word 
,Trans_AR=@Trans_AR 
,Trans_EN=@Trans_EN 

WHERE Id=@Id
END

Comment: @KarremSaad I hope that you do know sql, right ?, do you know what you need to remove from this line ? or not ? If you have set the Trans_AR as read, you remove the  ",Trans_AR=@Trans_AR"